# Multiple webview or current webview?

Tags: android, menu, webview

Hi all :D I'm new in android.

When I open application in webview I see Page1 (index.html), but when I click on Page2(index2.html)  I see Page2. Now are this multiple webview or current webview...

See on image:
http://oi57.tinypic.com/282jedv.jpg

I'm make like this `webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");`

In index.html I'm make fixed bar with open links in the same frame http://i60.tinypic.com/mb20s1.png

When you click on page2 (index2.html) open index2.html from `file:///android_asset/`... but when you click on Page1 (index.html) open index.html form `file:///android_asset/`

Answer (score 0):

override this method of webviewclient : shouldOverrideUrlLoading() so that every link opens in the same webview and in the same tab.

Hope this will help you.

Thank you.