# Current webview or multiple webview?

Tags: android, menu, webview

Hi all :D I'm new in android.

When I open application in webview I see Page1 (index.html), but when I click on Page2(index2.html) I see Page2. Now are this multiple webview or current webview...

See on image: http://oi57.tinypic.com/282jedv.jpg

I'm make like this  `webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");`

In index.html I'm make fixed bar with open links in the same frame http://i60.tinypic.com/mb20s1.png

When you click on page2 (index2.html) open index2.html from `file:///android_asset/`... but when you click on Page1 (index.html) open index.html form `file:///android_asset/`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple webview or current webview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858633/multiple-webview-or-current-webview)

Comment: Please stop duplicating your [own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858633/multiple-webview-or-current-webview). Edit old question with more information.

Comment: Yes I'm edit my old but I don't know how to make my old question to the top for android

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the property of WebView. If you are using Kitkat version or more, you can verify it by using chrome://inspect.

If you want to open all links within same webView, you can override a method called shouldOverrideUrlLoading() of WebViewClient.

Thank you.